# Is there a command to determine the compression ratio of a tar.bz2 file?

Tags: linux, zip, gzip, tar

I have a file.tar.bz2 that's about 50GB and would like to extract it however I don't know how much space I will need.  Is there a command to print the compression ratio of the tar.bz2 file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a command specifically for printing out compression ratios, but

```
bzip2 -dc file.tar.bz2 | wc -c
```

should show you the number of bytes taken up by the uncompressed tar file.  Some of that space is taken up by the tar metadata, but it should give you a ballpark estimate.

Answer (score 6):

```
tar -tvjf file.tar.bz2
```

Will list all the files in the tar file, their respective sizes, and other information.  You could always pipe the output through an awk script to add up the numbers...

```
tar -tvjf file.tar.bz2 | awk '{i+=$3;print i"     "$0}' | tail
```

Comment: or `tar -tvjf file.tar.bz2 | awk '{i+=$3} END{print i}'` - will only print the sum of all sizes

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as this is where search brought me for doing the same thing with .tar.gz files, so I'll add that

```
tar -tvf file.tar.gz | awk '{i+=$3} END{print i}'
```

will work for those.  ie just leave out the j that specifies bz2 format. I would of posted this as a comment @TooLazyToLogIn's post but I don't have the rep for that.